# Spring AOP Error: error Type referred to is not an annotation type

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I declared a annotation of Action

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface Action {
    String name();
}
```

When I tried to make a Pointcut

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class LogAspect {
    @Pointcut("@annotation(com.wisely.highlight_spinrg4.ch1.aop.Action)") //it failed here
    public void annotationPointCut() {}

    @After("annotationPointCut()")
    public void after(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature)
        joinPoint.getSignature();
        Method method = signature.getMethod();
        Action action = method.getAnnotation(Action.class);
        System.out.println("Annotation Interpreter " + action.name());      
    }

    @Before("execution(*com.wisely.highlight_spring4.ch1.aop.DemoMethodService.*(..))")
    public void before(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature)
        joinPoint.getSignature();
        Method method = signature.getMethod();
        System.out.println("Method Interpreter" + method.getName());
    }
}
```

It threw an error:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error Type referred to is not an annotation type: com$wisely$highlight_spinrg4$ch1$aop$Action

I've no idea since I used @interface to set “Action” as annotation. Could anyone offer some help?

Comment: I guess the type is in the package name? `spinrg4` should be `spring4` I guess...

Comment: That is the problem! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try running a maven clean and install if you are using Maven. I suspect the Action annotation have the same name of a class or an interface inside one of your dependency and it's taking the wrong object for some reason.